# Setting up Nginx with Vagrant and Chef

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

Starting over. :P @crum2 Tried the apt-get update but no luck. :\ I did although speak to my friend and he mentioned I was using a box of his that isn't the most reliable. So there's a way to save a .box? Is that after provisioning via chef etc? Need to do more reading... obviously. So I changed to the following:

Vagrantfile

```
  # -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.network :public_network

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "nginx"
  end

end
```

I've created my own cookbooks directory and downloaded only what I believe is needed according to: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx

Cookbooks

```
   |__build-essential
   |__nginx
   |__ohai
   |__runit
```

Terminal Output

```
mac-mini:test admin$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'precise64'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Ethernet
2) en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
What interface should the network bridge to? 1
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running any VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] -- /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
[default] Running provisioner: VagrantPlugins::Chef::Provisioner::ChefSolo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 10.14.2 ***
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[nginx]"] from JSON
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[nginx]]
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [nginx]
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2013-04-15T23:42:59+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: ohai plugins will be at: /etc/chef/ohai_plugins
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] action create (ohai::default line 30)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] action create (dynamically defined)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] created directory /etc/chef/ohai_plugins
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] mode changed to 755
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README] action create (dynamically defined)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README] mode changed to 644
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: cookbook_file[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README] created file /etc/chef/ohai_plugins/README
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] created directory /etc/chef/ohai_plugins
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] mode changed to 755
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing ohai[custom_plugins] action reload (ohai::default line 44)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: ohai[custom_plugins] reloaded
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing ohai[reload_nginx] action nothing (nginx::ohai_plugin line 22)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] action create (nginx::ohai_plugin line 27)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] updated content
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] owner changed to 0
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] group changed to 0
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] mode changed to 755
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/nginx.rb] sending reload action to ohai[reload_nginx] (immediate)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing ohai[reload_nginx] action reload (nginx::ohai_plugin line 22)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: ohai[reload_nginx] reloaded
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing remote_directory[/etc/chef/ohai_plugins] action nothing (ohai::default line 30)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing ohai[custom_plugins] action nothing (ohai::default line 44)
[2013-04-15T23:43:00+00:00] INFO: Processing package[nginx] action install (nginx::default line 35)

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[nginx]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
apt-get -q -y install nginx=1.1.19-1 returned 100, expected 0

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb

 34:   end
 35:   package node['nginx']['package_name']
 36:   service 'nginx' do

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:35:in `from_file'

package("nginx") do
  retry_delay 2
  retries 0
  recipe_name "default"
  action :install
  cookbook_name :nginx
  package_name "nginx"
end

[2013-04-15T23:43:04+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-04-15T23:43:04+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-04-15T23:43:04+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-04-15T23:43:04+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[nginx] (nginx::default line 35) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: apt-get -q -y install nginx=1.1.19-1 returned 100, expected 0
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Chef Stacktrace

```
Generated at Mon Apr 15 23:43:04 +0000 2013
Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[nginx] (nginx::default line 35) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: apt-get -q -y install nginx=1.1.19-1 returned 100, expected 0
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:128:in `handle_command_failures'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:75:in `run_command'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:143:in `run_command_with_systems_locale'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package/apt.rb:97:in `install_package'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider/package.rb:81:in `action_install'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:63:in `call'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:63:in `converge!'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:61:in `each'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:61:in `converge!'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:136:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/provider.rb:125:in `run_action'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource.rb:593:in `run_action'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:92:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:378:in `converge'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:420:in `do_run'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:176:in `run'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:230:in `run_application'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `loop'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:218:in `run_application'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:70:in `run'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.14.2/bin/chef-solo:25
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo:19
```

So what am I missing here guys? Feel free to point me toward good reading material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out after adding apt after all resolved my issues and this guy seems to have figured this out now. This helped: [Error with Chef build-essential cookbook on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555096/error-with-chef-build-essential-cookbook-on-ubuntu-12-04). Delete this or leave it. :P

Answer (score 3):

Somehow APT was not able to install the nginx package in version 1.1.19-1 - did you specify that version manually? Maybe run an `apt-get update` inside the box to refresh package index and try again (maybe the old nginx package is not available due to updates).